# Javascript window is undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

Here is some of my javascript:

```js
(function(window) {
  window.file = {};
  file.i = 0;
  
  for(;;) {
     if(file.i++ >= 10) break;
     document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(file.i))
  } 
  
 
}) ();
```

Why is window undefined?

Comment: `window` is supposed to be the global object. You probably wouldn't need to pass it to function. Also note that `document` is a property of `window`.

Comment: I do that so it is more readable, and sometimes i like to pass a different object rather than window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call the anonymous function with `window` as the first argument:

```js
(function(window) {
  window.file = {};
  file.i = 0;
  
  for(;;) {
     if(file.i++ >= 10) break;
     document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(file.i))
  } 
}) (window);
```

Since you provided nothing, `window` inside of your function's scope was considered `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
(function(window) {
  window.file = {};
  file.i = 0;
  
  for(;;) {
     if(file.i++ >= 10) break;
     document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(file.i))
  } 
  
 
})(window);
```

Comment: @EternalDarkness is the same - when I write my answer and post it - then I see that you post similar answer few seconds earlier